# Resize images in codeginiter

Tags: php, codeigniter, image-manipulation

currently I'm working with codeigniter framework but I'm confused how to resize the image. I have followed the documentation but I'm still confused. This is my code

```
public function create(){
        //Check login
        if(!$this->session->userdata('logged_in')){
            redirect('users/login');
        }

        $data['title'] = 'Create Post';

        $data['categories'] = $this->BlogModel->get_categories();

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('title','title','required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('content','content','required');

        if($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE){
            $this->load->view('frontend/header');
            $this->load->view('frontend/navbar');
            $this->load->view('frontend/blog/create',$data);
            $this->load->view('frontend/footer');   
        } else{

            //Upload Image
            $config['upload_path'] = './assets/images/posts/blog';
            $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
            $config['max_size'] = '2048';
            $config['max_width'] = '0';
            $config['max_height'] = '0';

            $this->load->library('upload', $config);

            if(!$this->upload->do_upload()){
                $errors = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
                $post_image = 'noimage.jpg';
            }else{
                $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
                $post_image = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
            }

            $this->BlogModel->create_post($post_image);

            //set message
            $this->session->set_flashdata('post_created','Your post has been created');

            redirect('blog');
        }
    }
```

Please advice how to resize the image.

Thanks!

Comment: https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/image_lib.html#id2

Comment: hi @LawrenceCherone I have tried the documentation, the images can be uploded to my folder, but for resize images is still not working [link](https://pastebin.com/raw/TyxMdpFb)

Comment: ^ nowhere in that code (which you should have included here instead of what you have above) do you load the image lib class (you just init it - not the same thing)... how is this not giving you errors? are you developing without errors on? did you autoload it or load it somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do different things like resize the original image directly, rather than creating a thumb set `create_thumb` to false, and do not use `new_image`. The only difference between `create_thumb` and `new_image` is that `new_image` allows you to specify your own path and name. Whereas the most you can do with `create_thumb` is change the `thumb_marker`. Which is all in the [docs](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/image_lib.html#CI_Image_lib::resize)...

```
    //Upload Image
    $config['upload_path'] = './assets/images/posts/blog';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
    $config['max_size'] = '2048';
    $config['max_width'] = '0';
    $config['max_height'] = '0';

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    if (!$this->upload->do_upload()) {
        //$errors = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
        exit($this->upload->display_errors());
        $post_image = 'noimage.jpg';
    } else {
        $up_data = $this->upload->data();
        $post_image = $up_data['name'];

        $config = array(); // clear prev config

        $config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
        $config['source_image'] = $up_data['full_path'];
        $config['create_thumb'] = TRUE;
        $config['thumb_marker'] = '_thumbnail';
        $config['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
        $config['width'] = 75;
        $config['height'] = 50;

        $this->load->library('image_lib', $config);

        if(!$this->image_lib->resize()) {
            exit($this->image_lib->display_errors());
        }

        $thumb_path = $up_data['file_path'] . $up_data['raw_name'] . $config['thumb_marker'] . $up_data['file_ext'];
    }
```

The exits you can remove later, but leave them for debugging until you figure out a way to properly message your errors (I suggest session vars). These functions should also be moved to a model.